# Displaying Blazor components on a page based on its top and left position

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server application with few components on a page.
These components are draggable and as the user drags I save every
Top position and left position to the database.

I use the loop below to display the components on my page and when loaded
the components stack on one another.

```
     @foreach (var group in MyModel)
        {
            <div class="draggable position-absolute" id="@extgroup.AddId">
                <MyComponent
                    Id="@extgroup.AddId"
                    GroupDescription="@extgroup.Description"
                    TopPosition="@extgroup.TopPosition"
                    LeftPosition="@extgroup.LeftPosition">
                </MyComponent>
            </div>
        }
```

How can I display the components in the exact position they were
saved since I have all the values for top position and left position?

Thanks.

Comment: Components have no intrinsic position.  It's the HTML elements inside the component that have position.  So:

Comment: They are each within a div so how do I go about this?

Comment: I recommend putting `class="draggable position-absolute"` inside the component, and letting the component save and load its own position, i.e. make it a true independent control.  I would pass the entire `extgroup` as a single Parameter into the component.

Answer (score 0):

**MyComponent.razor**

```
<div style="position:absolute; left: @extgroup.LeftPosition; top: @extgroup.TopPosition">

   (Put your content here)

</div>
```